# Regex Pattern to Match A Href and Remove

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I am trying to create a regex to match all a href links that contain my domain and I will end up removing the links. It is working fine until I run into an a href link that has another HTML tag within the tag.

**Regex Statement:**

```
(<a[^<]*coreyjansen\.com[^<]*>)([^"]*?)(<\/a>)
```

**It matches the a href links in this statement with no problem**

```
Need a lawyer? Contact <span style="color: #000000"><a 
href="http://coreyjansen.com/">Random text is great</a> <a 
href="http://coreyjansen.com/practice/family/">Corey is awesome</a></span>
```

**It is unable to match both of the a href links this statement:**

```
<strong><a href="http://coreyjansen.com/"><img class="alignright size-full 
wp-image-12" src="http://50h0.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/lawyers.jpg" 
alt="lawyers" width="250" height="250" /></a>
```

I have been trying to play with the neglected character set with no luck. If I remove the neglected character set what ends up happening is it will match two links that are right after each other such as example 2 as one match.

Comment: Use a parser for your programing language instead!

Comment: Instead of searching through HTML tags, why don't you search for your domain throughout the HTML code and then decide (manually) which links do and don't belong. This prevents you from needing a parser and will also catch things like javascript redirects, css links, image tags, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that `[^<]*>` matches everything up until last `>`. That's the greedy behaviour of `*` asterisk. You can make it non-greedy by appending `?` after asterisk(which you already do in other part of your query). It will then match everything until first occurrence of `>`. Then you have to change the middle part of your regex too ie. to catch everything until first tag `</a>` like this:

```
(<a[^<]*coreyjansen\.com[^<]*?>)(.*?)(<\/a>)
```

Comment: That worked awesome. Now with the last match I am trying to issolate it so I can remove the A href and this is the expression I am using

  `/href\s*=\s*[\'|"]\s*(.*)\s*[\'|"]/i`

However it is now matching outside of the a href tag

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly. Are you trying to extract only `href=...` from anchor `<a>` tag? If so then your issue will be again with greediness of `(.*)` in your regexp. In this case it will match anything until last single or double quote.

Answer (score 1):

Use below regex which matches only `a` tag

```
(<a[^>]*coreyjansen\.com[^>]*>)
```

Example data

```
<strong><a href="http://coreyjansen.com/"><img class="alignright size-full 
wp-image-12" src="http://50h0.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/lawyers.jpg" 
alt="lawyers" width="250" height="250" /><a href="http://coreyjansen.com/"><a href="http://coreyjansen.com/"/></a>
```

Above regex will match all three `a` tag with your required domain.

Try above on [regex](http://regexr.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm playing with the following regex and it seems to be working:

```
<a.*coreyjansen\.com.*</a>
```

it captures anything between anchor tags that contain your site name. I am using javascript pattern matching from www.regexpal.com, depending on the language it could be slightly different

Answer (score 0):

You need to match start of tag `<a` then match address before `>` char. You are matching wrong char. When you match that, then everithing between `<a>` and `</a>` is displayed link. I don't know why you compare to not contain quotes, every tag attribute (in HTML5) has value inside quotes, so you need to match everything except link ending tag `</a>`. It's done by `((?!string to not match).)*` and after that should follow `</a>`. The result regex is:

```
(<a[^>]*coreyjansen\.com[^>]*>)((?!<\/a>).)*(<\/a>)
```